# How to create 32 bit version of Python code from 64 bit

Tags: python, pyinstaller, 32bit-64bit

I created a 64 bit version of my python code using pyinstaller. However, I would like to create a 32 bit version. It seems like I would need to download a 32 bit version of python and redo my entire code in that version which seems like a lot of work. Is there no simple method of achieving my goal without having to redo everything?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to rewrite any of your Python code, you'll just need a 32-bit Python interpreter which you can use to run PyInstaller. You should be able to install a 32-bit interpreter alongside your 64-bit one; check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187072/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-3-32-bit-and-64-bit-on-windows-side-by-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you actually have to run in 64 bit should work in a 32 bit environment. What you should make sure is that dependencies you are using in your code also work in 32 bit.